# Play framework template For Loop

Tags: templates, playframework

I am trying to create a for loop in a play framework template like this :

```
 <ul>
  #{list items:1..${pageCount}, as:i}
       <li> <a href="#">${i}</a></li>
  #{/list}
 </ul>
```

How ever , it can not work because of this: items:1..${result.count} . I there a way of achieving the same:

Context: I am implementing pagination and  i need to create a link that will take the user to the specified page. May  be there is a 'play' way or achieving the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove ${} from pageCount :

```
#{list items:1..pageCount, as:'i'}

${i} ${i.id} ${i.price}

#{/list}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can i make a general conclusion that when am already inside a tag, i can access other values without using ${} but when am in the html markup, i have to use ${} to access values. ??

Comment: When you are in a tag, you don't need to use ${}: it's as if you were in a part of code directly accessing variables from the context. So you don't need to specify it's a variable with ${}.

Comment: I don't know if older versions but 1.2.1 needs to be like this
#{list items:1..pageCount, as:'i'}